# Currency symbol not displaying correctly on Saleor platform

Tags: django, currency, saleor

Please I have some issue with displaying the right currency symbol for Naira in saleor platform.
In the documentation, I saw it could be changed by redefining **DEFAULT_CURRENCY** in *settings.py*

```
DEFAULT_CURRENCY = os.environ.get("DEFAULT_CURRENCY", "USD")
```

How I approached the issue:

- Saleor-platform default currency came with **USD** which displayed **$** as the currnecy symbol (e.g **$** 1000)
- Then I changed it to **NGN** but it displayed **NGN** as the currency symbol (e.g **NGN** 1000) instead of ₦1000
- And then I tried changing it to EUR and it displayed **€** as the currency symbol (e.g **€**1000)

Maybe minor countries where not considered while building the platform. Please could there be a way to tweak this? see screenshot of the display below:

[saleor currency display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inkPz.png)